# Angular 1: Directive doesn't show after I come back to page a second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working on this website, and I've encountered something new to me. I wrote a series of directives to use as components for organization, and I can't get them to communicate just fine, and they will load on a page refresh or anything other type of refresh, but if I switch views nothing shows up when I return to the page with a directive on it.

**Example**

1. Visit page and land on home screen.
2. Go to builder page (this has the directive)
3. Everything triggers correctly on the first load of the page
4. Decide I need to go to the "About Us" page for a second
5. Return to the builder page. Nothing is happening this time.

I can't tell if an error is being thrown, or what, but nothing is showing up for me. Here is the code for everything below:

deckbuilder.controller.js

```
angular.module('dbs').controller('deckbuilderController', DeckbuilderController);

DeckbuilderController.$inject = ['$scope', 'deckbuilderService', 'cardsService', '$http', '$location', 'loginService', 'loaderService', '$routeParams', 'chartsService', 'utilityService'];

function DeckbuilderController($scope, deckbuilderService, cardsService, $http, $location, loginService, loaderService, $routeParams, chartsService, utilityService){
    
    $scope.submitDisabled = true;
    $scope.deck;
    $scope.tabView = 0;

    $scope.deckColorChart = chartsService.getColorChart();
    $scope.deckCurveChart = chartsService.getCurveChart();
    $scope.deckComboChart = chartsService.getComboChart();

    
    $scope.editing = false;
    $scope.catalog = {
        leaders: [],
        cards: {}
    };

    $scope.colorView = 1;
    $scope.searchView = 1;

    $scope.updateTitle = function(){
        deckbuilderService.setTitle($scope.deck.title);
    };

    $scope.updateNotes = function(){
        deckbuilderService.setNotes($scope.deck.notes);
    };
    
    $scope.updatePrivate = function(){
        deckbuilderService.setPrivate($scope.deck.is_private);
    };

    $scope.setSearchTab = function(tab){
        $scope.searchView = tab;
    };

    $scope.getRowColor = function(color){
        return utilityService.getTableRowColor(color);
    }

    $scope.private = [
        {id: 0, name: "No"},
        {id: 1, name: "Yes"}
    ];

    // catch the leaderChanged event to update the view
    // service is already updated at this point
    $scope.$on("leaderChanged", function(event, data){
        $('.leader-image').popover('hide');
        $scope.deck = deckbuilderService.getDeck();
        $scope.searchView = 2;
        $scope.invalid = deckbuilderService.checkInvalid();
        $scope.$apply();
    });
    $scope.$on("cardAdded", function(event, args){
        $('.card-image').popover('hide');
        $scope.deck = deckbuilderService.getDeck();
        chartsService.setColorChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        chartsService.setCurveChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        chartsService.setComboChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        $scope.deckColorChart = chartsService.getColorChart();
        $scope.deckCurveChart = chartsService.getCurveChart();
        $scope.deckComboChart = chartsService.getComboChart();
        $scope.invalid = deckbuilderService.checkInvalid();
        $scope.$apply();
    });

    $scope.$on('cardsFiltered', function(event, args){
        $scope.catalog.cards = args.cards;
        $scope.colorView = args.colorView;
        $scope.$apply();
    });

    $scope.clearDeck = function(){
        deckbuilderService.clearDeck();
        $scope.deck = deckbuilderService.getDeck();
        chartsService.setColorChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        chartsService.setCurveChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        chartsService.setComboChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        $scope.deckColorChart = chartsService.getColorChart();
        $scope.deckCurveChart = chartsService.getCurveChart();
        $scope.deckComboChart = chartsService.getComboChart();
        $scope.invalid = deckbuilderService.checkInvalid();
        $scope.searchView = 1;
    };

    $scope.setTab = function(tab){
        $scope.tabView = tab;
        deckbuilderService.setMode(tab);
        if(tab === 2){
            $scope.deckColorChart = chartsService.getColorChart();
            $scope.deckCurveChart = chartsService.getCurveChart();
            $scope.deckComboChart = chartsService.getComboChart();
        }
    };

    $scope.addCard = function(c){
        deckbuilderService.addCard(c);
        $scope.deck = deckbuilderService.getDeck();
        chartsService.setColorChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        chartsService.setCurveChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        chartsService.setComboChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        $scope.deckColorChart = chartsService.getColorChart();
        $scope.deckCurveChart = chartsService.getCurveChart();
        $scope.deckComboChart = chartsService.getComboChart();
        $scope.invalid = deckbuilderService.checkInvalid();
    }

    $scope.removeCard = function(c){
        deckbuilderService.removeCard(c);
        $scope.deck = deckbuilderService.getDeck();
        chartsService.setColorChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        chartsService.setCurveChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        chartsService.setComboChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
        $scope.deckColorChart = chartsService.getColorChart();
        $scope.deckCurveChart = chartsService.getCurveChart();
        $scope.deckComboChart = chartsService.getComboChart();
        $scope.invalid = deckbuilderService.checkInvalid();
    }

    $scope.setColorTab = function(tab){
        $scope.colorView = tab;
        $scope.$broadcast('colorUpdated', {colorView: tab});
    };

    $scope.updateDeck = function(){
        loaderService.show();
        $scope.submitDisabled = true;
        deckbuilderService.updateDeck().then(function(response){
            loaderService.hide();
            $location.path('/decklists/community/viewlist/'+$routeParams.id);
        }).catch(function(err){
            $scope.submitDisabled = false;
        });
    };

    $scope.submitDeck = function(){
        loaderService.show();
        $scope.submitDisabled = true;
        loginService.checkLogin().then(function(response){
            if(response){
                deckbuilderService.submitDeck().then(function(response){
                    loaderService.hide();
                    $location.path('/decklists/community/viewlist/'+response.decklist__id);
                }).catch(function(err){
                    $scope.submitDisabled = false;
                });
            }else{
                $scope.submitDisabled = false;
                loaderService.hide();
                localStorage.setItem('returnTo', 'deckbuilder');
                $location.path('login');
            }
        });
    };

    loaderService.show();
    $scope.deck = deckbuilderService.getDeck();
    $scope.invalid = deckbuilderService.checkInvalid();
    if($routeParams.id != void 0){
        $scope.editing = true;
        deckbuilderService.loadDeck($routeParams.id).then(function(response){
            $scope.deck = deckbuilderService.getDeck(); 
            chartsService.setColorChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
            chartsService.setCurveChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
            chartsService.setComboChartData($scope.deck.main_board.cards);
            $scope.invalid = deckbuilderService.checkInvalid();
            loaderService.hide();
        });
    }else{
        $scope.invalid = deckbuilderService.checkInvalid();
        loaderService.hide();
    }
}
```

deckbuilderLeaderCatalog.directive.js

```
angular.module('dbs').directive('deckbuilderLeaderCatalog', DeckbuilderLeaderCatalogDirective);

DeckbuilderLeaderCatalogDirective.$inject = ['cardsService', 'loaderService'];

function DeckbuilderLeaderCatalogDirective(cardsService,loaderService){

    return{
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/deckbuilder/catalog/leader/deckbuilderLeaderCatalog.html',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.leaderColorView = 1;
            scope.setLeaderColorTab = function(tab){
                scope.leaderColorView = tab;
            };
            scope.catalog = {};
            loaderService.show();
            cardsService.load().then(function(response){
                scope.catalog = response;
                loaderService.hide();
            });
        }
    };
}
```

deckbuilderLeader.directive.js

```
angular.module('dbs').directive('deckbuilderLeader', DeckbuilderLeaderDirective);

DeckbuilderLeaderDirective.$inject = ['deckbuilderService'];

function DeckbuilderLeaderDirective(deckbuilderService){

    return{
        scope: {
            card : '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/deckbuilder/leader/deckbuilderLeader.html',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.image = '/img/leaders/'+scope.card.img_front;
            element.bind('click', function(){
                deckbuilderService.leader.set(scope.card);
                scope.$emit("leaderChanged");
            });
            
            // popover function
            $('.leader-image').popover({
                trigger: 'hover',
                container: 'body',
                html: true,
                title: scope.card.card_name,
                delay: {
                    "show" : 800
                },
                content: "<div class='row'>"+
                    "<div class='col-sm-12'>"+
                        "<table class='table table-sm'>"+
                            "<tr>"+
                                "<td>"+
                                    "<img src='img/leaders/"+scope.card.img_front+"' width='50%' />"+
                                "</td>"+
                                "<td>"+
                                    "<img src='img/leaders/"+scope.card.img_back+"' width='50%' />"+
                                "</td>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                        "</table>"+
                    "</div>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<div class='row'>"+
                    "<div class='col-sm-12'>"+
                        "<p>"+scope.card.card_front_text+"</p>"+
                        "<p><strong>Awakened</strong><br>"+scope.card.card_back_text+"</p>"+
                    "</div>"+
                "</div>"
            });
        }
    };
}
```

**deckbuilderView.html**

```
<view-header nav-active="decklists"></view-header>
<main class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <nav class='col-sm-12'>
            <ol class='breadcrumb'>
                <li class='breadcrumb-item'><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class='breadcrumb-item active'>Deck Builder</li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <!-- maindeck/sidedeck tabs -->
        <aside class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-3'>
            <article class='card text-white bg-dark '>
                <div class='card-header'>
                    Deck Info
                </div>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <form class='mt-2 pb-2'>
                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12'>
                            <label>Deck Title</label>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-sm' name='deckTitle' ng-model='deck.title' ng-change="updateTitle()"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12'>
                            <label>Deck Notes (Optional)</label>
                            <textarea class='form-control form-control-sm deck-notes' name='deckNotes' ng-model='deck.notes' ng-change="updateNotes()"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-sm-6'>
                            <label>Is Private?</label>
                            <select name='isPrivate' id='isPrivate' class='form-control form-control-sm' ng-options="option.name for option in private track by option.id" ng-model="deck.is_private" ng-change="updatePrivate()"></select>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">

                </div>
            </article>
      <div class='vertical-nav pt-2'>
                <article class='card text-white bg-dark' ng-if="!cardStats && !leaderStats">
                    <div class='card-header ellipsis' ng-click='showLeaderStats(deck.leader.card)'>
                        <strong>Deck Leader |</strong> {{deck.leader.card_name}}
                    </div>
                    <div class='card-body'>
                        <div class='btn-group btn-group-sm d-none d-sm-flex'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' ng-if='deck.main_board.cards.length' ng-click='clearDeck()'>Clear Deck</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class='btn-group btn-group-sm  d-none d-sm-flex'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn' ng-click='setTab(0)' ng-class="{'btn-primary' : tabView == 0 , 'btn-outline-primary' : tabView != 0}">
                                Main Deck | {{deck.main_board.qty}}
                            </button>
                            <button type='button' class='btn' ng-click='setTab(1)'  ng-class="{'btn-primary' : tabView == 1 , 'btn-outline-primary' : tabView != 1}">
                                Side Deck | {{deck.side_board.qty}}
                            </button>
                            <button type='button' class='btn' ng-click='setTab(2)' ng-class="{'btn-primary' : tabView == 2 , 'btn-outline-primary' : tabView != 2}">
                                Deck Stats
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <ul class='nav flex-column nav-pills d-block d-sm-none'>
                            <a class='nav-link active' ng-click="setTab(0)" ng-class='{active : tabView == 0}'>Main Deck <span class='badge badge-primary deck-count'>{{deck.main_qty}}</span></a>
                            <a class='nav-link' ng-click="setTab(1)" ng-class='{active : tabView == 1}'>Side Deck <span class='badge badge-primary deck-count'>{{deck.side_qty}}</span></a>
                            <a class='nav-link' ng-click="setTab(2)" ng-class='{active : tabView == 2}'>Deck Stats</a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="tabView == 0">
                        <table class='table decklist-table table-sm'>
                            <tr ng-repeat="m in deck.main_board.cards" ng-class="getRowColor(m.color)">
                                <td>{{m.qty}}</td>
                                <td ng-click="showCardStats(m)">{{m.card_name}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class='list-edit btn-group float-right'>
                                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm plus' ng-click="addCard(m)">+</button>
                                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm minus ' ng-click="removeCard(m)">-</button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="tabView == 1">
                        <table class='table decklist-table table-sm'>
                            <tr ng-repeat="s in deck.side_board.cards" ng-class="getRowColor(s.color)">
                                <td>{{s.qty}}</td>
                                <td ng-click="showCardStats(s)">{{s.card_name}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class='list-edit btn-group float-right'>
                                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm plus' ng-click="addCard(s)">+</button>
                                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm minus' ng-click="removeCard(s)">-</button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="tabView == 2">
                        <div google-chart chart="deckColorChart" style="height:250px; width:100%;color: white;background-color: black;"></div>
                        <div google-chart chart="deckCurveChart" style="height:250px; width:100%;color: white;background-color: black;"></div>
                        <div google-chart chart="deckComboChart" style="height:250px; width:100%;color: white;background-color: black;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='card-footer p-0 m-0'>
                        <div class='btn-group btn-group-sm d-sm-flex d-flex'>
                            <button class='btn btn-success btn-block' ng-click="submitDeck()" ng-if="!editing" ng-disabled="invalid">Submit Deck</button>
                            <button class='btn btn-success btn-block' ng-click="updateDeck()" ng-if="editing" ng-disabled="invalid">Update Deck</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </aside>

        <!-- deck preview -->
        <section class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8'>
            <article class='card bg-dark text-white'>
                <div class='card-header p-0 w-0'>
                    <div class='btn-group btn-group-sm w-100'>
                        <button type='button' class='btn w-50' ng-click='setSearchTab(1)' ng-class="{'btn-primary': searchView == 1, 'btn-outline-primary': searchView != 1}">Choose Leader</button>
                        <button type='button' class='btn w-50' ng-click='setSearchTab(2)' ng-class="{'btn-primary': searchView == 2, 'btn-outline-primary': searchView != 2}">Build Deck</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <section ng-show="searchView == 1">
                        <deckbuilder-leader-catalog></deckbuilder-leader-catalog>
                    </section>
                    <section ng-show="searchView == 2">
                        <deckbuilder-filters catalog="catalog"></deckbuilder-filters>
                        <deckbuilder-card-catalog></deckbuilder-card-catalog>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
<view-footer>
```

**leaderCatalogView.html**

```
<div class='btn-group btn-group-sm  d-flex d-sm-flex mb-4'>
    <button type='button' class='btn' ng-click='setLeaderColorTab(1)' ng-class="{'btn-danger' : leaderColorView == 1 , 'btn-outline-danger' : leaderColorView != 1}">Red</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn' ng-click='setLeaderColorTab(2)' ng-class="{'btn-primary' : leaderColorView == 2 , 'btn-outline-primary' : leaderColorView != 2}">Blue</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn' ng-click='setLeaderColorTab(3)' ng-class="{'btn-success' : leaderColorView == 3 , 'btn-outline-success' : leaderColorView != 3}">Green</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn' ng-click='setLeaderColorTab(4)' ng-class="{'btn-warning' : leaderColorView == 4 , 'btn-outline-warning' : leaderColorView != 4}">Yellow</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn' ng-click='setLeaderColorTab(5)' ng-class="{'btn-secondary' : leaderColorView == 5 , 'btn-outline-secondary' : leaderColorView != 5}">Black</button>
</div>
<div class='col'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 mb-4'  ng-repeat="l in leaders.red" ng-show="leaderColorView == 1">
            <deckbuilder-leader card="l"></deckbuilder-leader>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 mb-4'  ng-repeat="l in leaders.blue" ng-show="leaderColorView == 2">
            <deckbuilder-leader card="l"></deckbuilder-leader>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 mb-4'  ng-repeat="l in leaders.green" ng-show="leaderColorView == 3">
            <deckbuilder-leader card="l"></deckbuilder-leader>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 mb-4'  ng-repeat="l in leaders.yellow" ng-show="leaderColorView == 4">
            <deckbuilder-leader card="l"></deckbuilder-leader>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 mb-4'  ng-repeat="l in leaders.black" ng-show="leaderColorView == 5">
            <deckbuilder-leader card="l"></deckbuilder-leader>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**leader.html**

```
<img src="{{image}}" width="100%" class='leader-image'/>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML in builder page?

Comment: @TanDuong I have added these items in

Comment: You should work a minimal example of your problem. You can't expect us to review all this code. What line of code triggers what error?

Comment: That’s the problem. It’s not throwing any error